# Adding data to second column of Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `datagrid` `DGV`.  That `gridview` has a column of `"File Name"` and is populated by the name of the files you've selected in an `openfildialog`.  After performing the calculations I was putting the results in a second `datagrid` `DGV2` which you'll see I've commented out below as I'd like to instead put them on a second column next to their corresponding `"File Name"` on `DGV` and just use one `gridview`.  However this is just taking the last calculation and duplicating it on each row rather than the individual calculations (as they should all be diff)

So it should look like:

```
File1 4.5 
File2 3.5
```

Instead its just doing

```
File1  3.5
File2  3.5
```

I know I'm causing it, I've done something wrong here I'm just not sure how to fix it.

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_Hidden.Rows)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo();
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(row.Cells["colfilelocation"].Value.ToString());
                var data = lines.Where(line => (!line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier) && !line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier) && !line.EndsWith("0.00"))).ToList();

                if (data.Count > 1)
                {
                    var line = data[0];
                    var firstsplit = data[1].Split(splitter);
                    info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(firstsplit[0]);
                    var secondsplit = data[data.Count - 1].Split(splitter);
                    info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(secondsplit[0]);
                }
                info.finalnum = info.startvalue - info.endvalue;
            }
            //DGV2.Rows.Add(info.finalnum);
            for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DGV.Rows[i].Cells["colfiledata"].Value = info.finalnum;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The last thing your code seems to be doing is setting all rows that column to the `info.finalnum` of that last file. I think you only want to set for that particular file, not all.

Comment: you are setting every row in DGV to info.filenum in the for loop, which i bet is the value you are seeing duplicated.

Comment: Your both correct.  I see that also.  And I hate to sound moronic here but I'm not sure how to individualize this.  Is it easy enough to just edit what I have?  Any code suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DGV_Hidden and DGV contains same number of rows? or include what is the data in DGV and DGV_HIdden

Comment: @Hybridzz Yes same number of rows.  DGV just has the file names where as DGV_Hidden is the actual file location that is being used that doesn't need seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,
As you said you have similar data /number of rows, You just need to set the value while looping through your hidden grid. use the row index of the looping variable to get the correct row.

```
 private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV_Hidden.Rows)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo();
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(row.Cells["colfilelocation"].Value.ToString());
                var data = lines.Where(line => (!line.Contains(Data_Start_Point_Identifier) && !line.Contains(FSD__Line_Identifier) && !line.EndsWith("0.00"))).ToList();

                if (data.Count > 1)
                {
                    var line = data[0];
                    var firstsplit = data[1].Split(splitter);
                    info.startvalue = Convert.ToDouble(firstsplit[0]);
                    var secondsplit = data[data.Count - 1].Split(splitter);
                    info.endvalue = Convert.ToDouble(secondsplit[0]);
                }
                info.finalnum = info.startvalue - info.endvalue;
            }
         //set your value here
            DGV.Rows[row.Index].Cells["colfiledata"].Value = info.finalnum;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep that's all I needed.  Seems silly now.  Good lookin out!